# Using Powershell Compress-Archive for folders in C:\Program Files

Tags: powershell

Trying to compress a folder in the `C:\Program Files` using Powershell however getting the following error. Appreciate if anyone can help.

Command:

```
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command Compress-Archive -Path "C:\Program Files\avr\cache.dat" -Destinationpath "C:\Program Files\avr\bur\"
```

Error:

> ```
> Compress-Archive : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files\avr\cache.dat'.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Compress-Archive -Path C:\Program Files\avr\cache.dat -Destina ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo         : InvalidArgument: (:) [Compress-Archive], ParameterBindingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Compress-Archive
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read and follow `powershell /?` (built-in help):

```
-Command
…
To write a string that runs a Windows PowerShell command, use the format:
    "& {<command>}"
where the quotation marks indicate a string and the invoke operator (&)
causes the command to be executed.
```

Use

```
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& {Compress-Archive -Path 'C:\Program Files\avr\cache.dat' -Destinationpath 'C:\Program Files\avr\bur\'}"
```

Comment: Perfect JosefZ.. It worked !!!  Thanks allot for your help.. Can you help me the following error please.

I'm trying to rename the file with the date as follows but giving me the error..

powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& {Compress-Archive -Path 'C:\Program Files\avr\cache.dat' -Destinationpath 'C:\Program Files\avr\bur\Result_$((Get-Date).ToString('ddMMMyyyyHHmm'))'}"

Error: 2019-07-24 12:25:37 avtar Info <6033>: Begin STDERR from run-at-start:
Compress-Archive : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts 
argument 'ddMMMyyyyHHmm))'.

Comment: @SatyaA `powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& {Compress-Archive -Path 'C:\Program Files\avr\cache.dat' -Destinationpath """C:\Program Files\avr\bur\Result_$((Get-Date).ToString('ddMMMyyyyHHmm'))"""}"` should work. Tested using   much more simple `powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& {echo """C:\Program Files\avr\bur\Result_$((Get-Date).ToString('ddMMMyyyyHHmm'))"""}"`.

Comment: your suggestion is good always.. It worked this time without any issues. The above one will work only from cmd prompt but not powershell console which fulfilled my requirement at this moment. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The Powershell portion of your command will run as-is in the Powershell interface. But if you run it from a command prompt, you need to escape the quotes with backslashes. Like this:

```
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command Compress-Archive -Path \"C:\Program Files\avr\cache.dat\" -Destinationpath \"C:\Program Files\avr\bur\\"
```

Comment: This didn't work in my case @Doug Deden..

Comment: What didn't work? Can you provide the command that you ran, along with the error message?

Comment: this is the error I got..
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Anyhow, thanks for your suggestion too.. but at this moment it is solved